# Does anyone know how can I convert JavaScript file to typescript file?

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm-install

I have my JavaScript files in project. Now I want to convert my whole JavaScript code into typescript. So is there any tool or converter that converts my js code to ts.

I got npm command from google to convert JavaScript to typescript

```
$ npm install javaScript-to-typescript
```

from the following link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-to-typescript

Can anyone help me how can I use above command??

Comment: I think that library just converts js files to ts files (extension). It doesn't change js code to ts code. You need to do it yourself.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412164/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-javascript-files-to-typescript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a tool to convert JavaScript files to TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412164/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-javascript-files-to-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

This library will not convert the files automatically you have to do it manually. You should have a knowledge of Typescript to convert it.
You can find the steps on official documentation here.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html

Answer (score -4):

Just change the file extention from ".js" to ".ts" it works. Every JavaScript code is valid TypeScript.

Comment: this is not true